# Refreshing Power Bi data from a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online

I am working on a project where my data source is List in Sharepoint 365. Is the data refreshed automatically every time users open the report? Do we have to scheduled the refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must schedule the refresh. See: [Configure Scheduled Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh).